# image added dynamically to canvas isn't loading JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I try to crop an image into multiple parts I want to then show in a canvas.
I hold the coordinates in an array, like arr[i].x, arr[i].y, arr[i].cropHeight, arr[i].cropWidth. If I have three cropped parts, I will have three elements in the array.

When itarating over the array, I want to create canvases which I add to a div I have, with the ID "canvasList".

I iterate as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.id = "canvas"+ arr[i].x + arr[i].y;
                canvas.width = arr[i].width;
                canvas.height = arr[i].height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.myCustomData = {
                                            x:arr[i].x, 
                                            y:arr[i].y,
                                            wi: arr[i].width,
                                            he: arr[i].height
                                        };
                imageObj.src = 'example.jpg';
                imageObj.onload = function () {
                    var sourceX = this.myCustomData.x;
                    var sourceY = this.myCustomData.y;
                    var sourceWidth = this.myCustomData.wi;
                    var sourceHeight = this.myCustomData.he;
                    var destWidth = sourceWidth;
                    var destHeight = sourceHeight;
                    var destX = 0;
                    var destY = 0;
                    context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
                };
                document.getElementById('canvasList').appendChild(canvas);
            }
```

The problem is that when I have more than one object in arr, only the last object is shown in the page, and I don't understand why.

Please help me.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do you really have to create separate canvases?

Comment: not really, but if I were to use the same canvas, I thought that then I would have to save in a variable how much of the canvas is already in use (width and height), and that, combined with the fact that the width and height of the cropped parts are variable, didn't seem a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the source of your problems:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
```

In every iteration in your loop, you are defining the new canvas context as `context`. When your image is loaded (async), it will render all the cropped images on `context`.

Since you are loading the image async, the loop will finish before the image is loaded, which means that the `context` variable that you are using the the image.onload function, is equal to the last context set = the last crop object.

Therefore, all image.onload functions uses the last set context to render the image.

**fix**

```
imageObj.myCustomData = {
    x:arr[i].x, 
    y:arr[i].y,
    wi: arr[i].width,
    he: arr[i].height,
    context: context
};
```

add the context to your custom data object.

And use the set context to render your image:

```
this.myCustomData.context.drawImage( .. )
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavGenberg/ezpu8oor/

**EDIT**

And, ofcourse, it would me much better to load the image only once:

https://jsfiddle.net/GustavGenberg/Loyu9tvo/

Comment: thank you, I think I understand now. I thought loading wouldn't be a problem, since I didn't put the code into the .onload method. anyways, I think I'll have to study a little bit more about this issue.

Comment: It's about global variables. These errors can easely occur if you are using them... Good luck :)